# Set command in Range for every Cell

Tags: duplicates, selection

I have code duplicated Active Cell which I select, but I need a correction that allow me duplicate every Cell in Range which I will select.

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
Range(Selection.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(xCount, 0)).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

I want select Range (example A1:A50) and code will duplicate every cell in thiss Range